# Universal Image Loader namespace error

Tags: binding, reference, namespaces, xamarin, universal-image-loader

In Xamarin, I have added the "universal-image-loader-1.9.2-with-sources.jar" as a file in the "Jars" folder of a binding project, I have then built the application but I am getting one error.

Here is the error:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DiskLruCache' does not exist
>   in the namespace
>   'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Disc.Impl.Ext' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

Can I please have some help to get this code working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the binding project as a reference in your Startup project.
To do so click on References directory in you solution tree and select the binding project in the "Projects" tab.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Bindings Library project and then add this jar into the folder Jars.
For fixing error:

> The type or namespace name 'DiskLruCache' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Disc.Impl.Ext'

add to Transforms\Metadata.xml

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext']/class[@name='DiskLruCache']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```